# c++ starting a thread with methods of objects of another class in a vector

Tags: multithreading, class, c++11, vector

I have encountered a problem while using threads from c++11 thread library. In class Genetic I have stored some objects of class Island in a vector:

```
class Genetic{
private:
    vector<Island> islands;

public:
    Genetic(Map m, int nOfIslands):islands(nOfIslands, Island(m)) {}
};
```

now I want to do a method called populate (which is implemented in Island class) on each of the Islands in my vector:

```
vector<thread> threads (islands.size());
for (auto i = 0u; i < islands.size(); ++i){
    threads[i] = thread([=] { islands[i].populate; });
}

for (auto &t : threads){
    t.join();
}
```

It results in following errors:

```
error C3867: 'Island::populate': function call missing argument list; use'&Island::populate' to create a pointer to member
```

Without threads everything is working correctly so I am not worried for code logic. Please tell me what I am doing wrong with threads and how can I make it work?

Comment: `islands[i].populate();` you forgot the `()`. I doubt that you want to copy the whole vector, though.

Comment: You are right, I was looking for bigger solutions so I completly forgot about the simple ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You create the threads using:

```
threads[i] = thread([=] { islands[i].populate; });
```

Note that `islands[i].populate` in the body of the lambda is an expression statement. You probably meant `islands[i].populate();` or similar instead.

Additionally, consider passing `i` and `this` to the lambda explicitly to improve clarity:

```
threads[i] = thread([this, i] { islands[i].populate; });
```